# Creating Domain Mapping on GCP CloudRun with domain managed by Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, cloud, cloudflare, google-cloud-run

I was wondering if anyone has any experience with creating a mapped domain within GCP's Cloud Run with on a domain that is managed by Cloudflare.

When I do so, I end up getting a 525 (SSL Handshake Failed). With limited visibility as to what is happening on GCP's side, I can't really debug what the issue is.

Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer here, turns our Cloudflare isn't currently supported by CloudRun: https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#how-can-i-configure-cdn-for-cloud-run-services

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by disabling Cloudflare security, HTTPS rewrites and browser integrity checks for the ACME challenge [as described in their community forum](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/outlook-suddenly-shows-an-error-message-that-the-cloudflare-certificate-is-not-trusted/532690/14). The latter is because otherwise Google is getting blocked by Cloudflare (this can be verified in your security events).

If it helps, this is the Terraform setup I'm using:

```
## Variables

variable "domain_suffix" {
  type        = string
  description = "The domain suffix used by all subdomains."
  default     = "example.com"
}

variable "domain_prefix" {
  type        = string
  description = "The subdomain prefix."
  default     = "sub"
}

variable "cloud_run_location" {
  type        = string
  description = "The location of the Cloud Run services."
  default     = "us-central1"
}

locals {
  full_domain = "${domain_prefix}.${domain_suffix}"
}


## Cloudflare resources

resource "cloudflare_record" "subdomain" {
  zone_id = var.cloudflare_zone_id
  name    = var.domain_prefix
  value   = "ghs.googlehosted.com"
  type    = "CNAME"
  proxied = true
}

# Disable security and browser integrity checks for the ACME challenge as GCP needs it for custom domain mapping
resource "cloudflare_page_rule" "acme_challenge_bypass" {
  zone_id = var.cloudflare_zone_id
  target  = "${local.full_domain}/.well-known/acme-challenge/*"
  actions {
    automatic_https_rewrites = "off"
    browser_check            = "off"
    cache_level              = "bypass"
    security_level           = "essentially_off"
  }
}


## Cloud Run resources

resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "default" {
  name     = "cloudrun-service"
  location = var.cloud_run_location
  template {
    containers {
      image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_cloud_run_domain_mapping" "default" {
  location = var.cloud_run_location
  name     = local.full_domain
  metadata {
    namespace = var.project
  }
  spec {
    route_name = google_cloud_run_v2_service.default.name
  }
}
```

With this setup all my domains get verified and working within 20 minutes.